# Adding Undersized Fuse to Doorbell Circuit?

Tags: electrical, doorbell

So recently my doorbell button got stuck and it burnt out both the electromagnetic coil in the chime *and* the transformer. As I'm replacing everything I was thinking that I could add fuse to prevent a rogue button from causing so much damage again.

The transformer is 16VAC 10W and I measured the voltage as just over 20VAC. The chime consists of an electromagnetic coil that drives a pin hitting a chime (separate coils for the front and back buttons). It claims it's suitable for a 16VAC 10W or 16VAC 15W transformer.

[image: Circuit diagram]

Let's say that *x* amps run through the circuit when the button is depressed. Normally the button is depressed for very short periods of time (let's say <10 seconds for an enthusiastic doorbell ringer). I've read that a fuse can withstand more than its rated current for a period of time depending of how high the current is over the rated current... can I undersize a fuse such that the blow time for an *x* amp load would be 10–15 seconds? Would sizing the fuse be so finicky as to be not worth it?

Comment: Instead of a fuse, I wonder whether a suitable PTC thermistor could be found that would have an appropriate thermal time constant.

Comment: @user43744  This is a nicely written question.  However, it deals with house wiring, and as such, it's off-topic on EE.SE .  There is a stack dedicated to home improvement, which is where I'm migrating this question.

Comment: Are you sure you're fixing a problem that actually exists? If you mind the switch (maybe check it once a year?) and replace it if it shows the least bit of wear you shouldn't have this problem again. Also how old was the old switch and chime and transformers?

Comment: Also does your new chime continue to ring or does it get stuck on and buzz if your switch gets stuck on? In other words will it fail or just keep ringing if the switch sticks?

Comment: @Freiheit it gets stuck on with the solenoid holding the pin against the chime and buzzes. Eventually this causes the solenoid to overheat. The chime and transformer were many years old but in good condition. The button had been recently replaced and was only a couple months old (I guess it was defective).

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't a slow-blow fuse work? I don't think you'd want to under size it. Just understand what voltage/current ratings you need and find a slow-blow fuse that can handle 10-15 seconds of that.

Something like [this](http://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/fuses/littelfuse_fuse_385_datasheet.pdf.pdf). Just figure out where you need to be on the Average Time Current Curves.

Comment: 10W at 16–20V would put me at 0.5–0.625A... I think the 0315 from the [396 series](http://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/fuses/littelfuse_fuse_396_datasheet.pdf.pdf) would work. I don't have a multimeter that can measure >0.2A but I'm assuming that if the electromagnetic coil is energized holding the pin against the chime the resistance would be very low.

Comment: Can't you find the coil resistance by removing the chime from the circuit and using your multimeter? That will give you the minimum resistance (maximum power) that your chime will use.

Comment: 7.5 Ohms, so 2.6A? It's been a while since I've done this. That's quite a bit higher than I expected.

Comment: That's what ohms law would state. If you're driving it from a transformer though, it probably drops to around (or slightly below) 16 volts under load. That would make it around 2.13 Amps. It's not terribly surprising that the designers under-spec'd the transformer and coil as they never expected it to be held down for long periods of time. You could try out one of the fuses shown in the link and see how long it would take for the fuse to blow.

Answer (score 2):

A good old bimetallic strip positioned close to the bell can open the circuit to prevent excessive over-heating.

[image]

As the bell solenoid gets a little warm, the bimetal elements warp mechanically and open circuit the bell current. After it has cooled down a bit the contacts close: -

[image]

Comment: But I'd probably have to build it from scratch, right?

Comment: Try ebay http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/sis.html?_nkw=KSD9700%20110C%20N%20C%20Bimetal%20Temperature%20Control%20Switch%20Thermo%20Protector&_itemId=400409939881 BUT read the spec to make sure it is suitable and is normally closed at low temperatures and opens at the correct temperature.

Comment: That's great! Thanks! The lowest I can find is 40C... that should be good, I think.

Comment: Self-resetting thermal breaker is another name for these, commonly used in automotive circuits where you have similar problems, something sticks, but it's the prolonged current, not overcurrent that is the issue. The intermittent circuit operation is the failure indicator, a constantly ringing doorbell would alert you that the button was stuck.

Comment: @FiascoLabs Actually older vehicles used something like this to control their turn signals.

Comment: Yep, Thermal Resetting Breakers and Bimetalic Turn/Emergency Signal Flashers. One neat thing was you could tell by the frequency of the flash if all bulbs were lit (burned filament slow or no flash). Adding a trailer made them work like they had heart arrhythmia.

Comment: @FiascoLabs: If the amount of current involved would be appropriate for such devices, an old-fashioned automotive blinker might be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Having had doorbell problems myself, I feel your pain.

I would recommend against this kind of hack. Consider what would happen if an overly enthusiastic Girl Guide decided to hold down your doorbell button.

From my personal experience, I found no problems holding down the doorbell continuously. This leads me to suspect that one of your components failed in some other way that violated the part's ratings. Perhaps some coils short circuited. Hopefully new parts rated to the power you specified will last longer.

Edit: As a tip, taping down your doorbell while inside testing connections is particularly helpful.

Comment: As the button was stuck and I didn't catch it I think it was held open continuously (possibly a couple days). :( If it was held continuously wouldn't the fuse just blow? I'd rather replace a fuse than the chime and transformer next time.

Comment: Perhaps my answer wasn't clear. My belief is that under normal operation (which includes holding the button), the components should be able to withstand the continuous current. Otherwise it seems unfathomable to me that houses around the world are operating a system that can be so easily destroyed.

You have two possible failure modes.
1. Doorbell systems can't withstand long term current.
2. You were subject to bad luck/age and your components just randomly failed creating condition 1.

I find #2 easier to believe.

Comment: I think that in the case of a door chime that operates with a solenoid pushing a pin mechanically against a chime this is something they are subject to. Take any solenoid and fix the load and run current through it for a prolonged period of time and it will overheat. Any electric fan is vulnerable to this failure mode as well.